# Error with org.slf4j.Logger

Tags: java, eclipse, import, slf4j

I have an error when I import the `org.slf4j.*` packages.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Do you have any ideas where it came from ?

Comment: it would be better if we did not have to guess the error...

Comment: Blue! (I figured that was as good of guess as any)

Comment: Presumably you have not downloaded and installed the jar files into eclipse?

Comment: @dotNet - post the error you are receiving. We're not psychic.

Comment: It's not an error it's just saying that the package is not recongnized

Comment: Actually, that *is* an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [SL4J (Simple Logging Facade for Java)](http://www.slf4j.org/). Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please explain how you solved this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: @8vius I suppose he solved adding the sl4j jar to the classpath. Have a look at the link in my answer.

Comment: Wow, incomplete question, incomplete self-answer.  Since other folks are following behind you, could you please edit your question and your answer to clarify the problem you had the solution you found, even if it was simple "pilot error"?

Answer (score 7):

You must include JARs in your classpath. I'd suggest the following:

- slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar

They can be found on: http://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

You either have manually organized imports, or asked Eclipse to do so every time you save your Java file.

This function expands *-imports to the individual classes needed.  This helps avoiding ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

At this situation, you can to add dependencies to org.slf4j.* packages, I think so. For example for Gradle:

compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'

More details here
[Gradle does not find dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30932526/gradle-does-not-find-dependencies)