# Gradle does not find dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle and the file looks like:

```
// Apply the java plugin to add support for Java
apply plugin: 'java'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'execute.Entry'
    }
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // The production code uses the SLF4J logging API at compile time
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.12'
    compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.3'

    // Declare the dependency for your favourite test framework you want to use in your tests.
    // TestNG is also supported by the Gradle Test task. Just change the
    // testCompile dependency to testCompile 'org.testng:testng:6.8.1' and add
    // 'test.useTestNG()' to your build script.
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

As you can see, I've added two dependencies and want to use in a class

```
package execute;

import message.*;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Entry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Service s = new Service();
        String msg = s.GetMessage();
        LOGGER.info("Received msg: " + msg);

    }
}
```

When I execute the statement `gradle assemble`, I've got the compiler error.

```
D:\Java\entrypoint\src\main\java\execute\Entry.java:4: error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
                       ^
D:\Java\entrypoint\src\main\java\execute\Entry.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
        LOGGER.info("Received msg: " + msg);
        ^
  symbol:   variable LOGGER
  location: class Entry
2 errors
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.261 secs
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
I changed my code to this:

```
package execute;

import message.*;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Entry {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Service s = new Service();
        String msg = s.GetMessage();
        logger.info("Hello, World!");

    }
}
```

The compiler complain:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
        at execute.Entry.<clinit>(Entry.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

**Update 2**
After execute:

```
>gradle dependencies
:dependencies                                                                    

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project                 
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies                                                   

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3                      

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3                      

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3                      

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3                          
\--- junit:junit:4.12        
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3                          
\--- junit:junit:4.12        
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: Just as an aside, don't you want to be logging against the SLF4J logger?

Comment: `LOGGER` isn't defined, so that's never going to work. Secondly, this is a partial error message. What task are you running and how.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you still need the log4j dependency itself: `compile: 'log4j:log4j:versionX'`

**Update 1**:

And ofcourse you should add:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DrglMutatieBerichtMdb.class);
```

**Update 2**:

I use the following dependencies:

```
compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
```

Than in the code I import:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

And use the logger like this:

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DrglMutatieBerichtMdb.class);

private static void testLogger(){
    logger.debug("The logger works!");
}
```

Comment: I went to the website http://search.maven.org/ type Log4j into input field, click on the newest version and there is a Dependency Information. Click then Gradle/Grails and copy compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j:2.3' into my gradle file. Is right to add a dependency?

Comment: Yes that is probably the rigfht one.

Comment: I use a different import: `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;`

Comment: Still compiler complain.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
```

use

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

and define the instance of LOGGER

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger("HelloWorld");
```

See this sample
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html

this has nothing todo with Gradle

Comment: what do you get when you do ```gradle dependencies```

Answer (score 0):

I also had to add to the dependencies:

`compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.3"`

Answer (score 0):

the first answer (@helox) helped in fixing the similar issue , i used gradle 7.1.1 and below is the snippet when included resolved the cannot find symbol of Logger error due the package not found for "org.apache.log4j.Logger"

```
testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32'
testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.32'
implementation 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```